# How to view certain file inside gem on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

Is there any way to open file inside ruby gem that installed on heroku server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gems will be the same as what you have defined in your Gemfile - that's the great thing about bundler..

```
bundle open gem_name
```

Comment: it works perfect on my local machine but how to do same on heroku server?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  The gem you have locally is the same as what Heroku is using - that is the entire point of Bundler.